# Failed to import cupy

Tags: cupy

After installing cupy via "pip install cupy-cuda110", I tried this in python3:

> > > import cupy as cp

However, it failed:

"
$ python3
Python 3.8.10 (default, Nov 26 2021, 20:14:08)
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

> > > import cupy as cp
> > > Traceback (most recent call last):
> > > File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/cupy/**init**.py", line 18, in 
> > > from cupy import _core  # NOQA
> > > File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/cupy/_core/**init**.py", line 1, in 
> > > from cupy._core import core  # NOQA
> > > ImportError: libnvrtc.so.11.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

## Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/cupy/**init**.py", line 20, in 
raise ImportError(f'''
ImportError:

Failed to import CuPy.

If you installed CuPy via wheels (cupy-cudaXXX or cupy-rocm-X-X), make sure that the package matches with the version of CUDA or ROCm installed.

On Linux, you may need to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable depending on how you installed CUDA/ROCm.
On Windows, try setting CUDA_PATH environment variable.

Check the Installation Guide for details:
https://docs.cupy.dev/en/latest/install.html

## Original error:
ImportError: libnvrtc.so.11.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

> > > 

"

May you know how to resolve this problem? Many thanks!

Comment: i got the same problem

Answer (score 3):

Before installing cupy, you should check the version of Cuda that is installed on your device :

```
!nvcc --version
```

For me, the Cuda version installed on my device is 11.0 (See the picture below) :
[image]

After that go to the official Cupy website https://docs.cupy.dev/en/stable/install.html

The following image is from the page I referred to above:
[image]

Then type the install command that matches your Cuda version, for me, the install command will be  :

```
pip install cupy-cuda110
```

Answer (score 0):

When installing these packages with CUDA 11.2, 11.3, or 11.4, you may experience a “Failed to import CuPy” error. To resolve this error, please uninstall cupy-cuda115 and install cupy-cuda11x:

```
pip uninstall cupy-cuda115
pip install cupy-cuda11x
```

https://rapids.ai/pip.html